# Bootstrap-datepicker How can I limit the rage between the start date chosen?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on my project and everything is working very well.

I am setting the `startDate` to `+7` days and the `endDate` to `+18m` as the earliest date that can be chosen is 7 days from the current date, and the furthest out a start date can be chosen is 18 months from the current date:

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    'todayHighlight': true,
    'toggleActive': true,
    'startDate': '+7d',
    'endDate': '+18m',
    'autoclose': true
});
```

Everything is working perfectly, I would like to limit the rage between the selected start date and the end date of 2 days and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

For example, if I choose a start date of 06/01/2016 the max end date is 06/03/2016. Even if I choose a start date that is six months from now, I only want the end date to be +2 days from the start date chosen.

I've been experimenting with `maxViewMode` and `startDate` but I believe I need the `startDate` and `endDate` properties set like I currently have them.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. I am setting a default start date of +7 days from the current date. The user can only select an end date that is +18 months from the current date as well. The user can select any start date, but the date of the end date is only +2 days from the start date.

**html**

```
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control from-date" name="start" id="my-id-one" data-id="1"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">through</span>
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control to-date" name="end" id="my-id-two" data-id="2"/>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.from-date').datepicker({ // Start Date
    'autoclose': true,
    'startDate': '+7d',
    'endDate': '+18m',
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    var rangeDate = new Date(selected.date.getTime() + (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    $('.to-date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate).datepicker('setEndDate', rangeDate);
}).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
    $('.to-date').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
});

$('.to-date').datepicker({ // End Date
    'autoclose': true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var endDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.from-date').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
}).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
    $('.from-date').datepicker('setEndDate', null);
});
```